# How to run JSF 2.0 in Google App Engine 1.6.5

Tags: google-app-engine, jsf, web-deployment

Ok so ive just finished my first JSF project and i want to upload it to GAE. I have been trying for about the last 4 hours and cannot make it work.

I am using JSF 2.0 and App Engine 1.6.5.

I have tried several tutorials and all combinations of the following:

[First tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/google-app-engine-jsf-2-example/comment-page-1/#comment-82266)

Jars - javax.faces-2.1.7-sources.jar el-ri-1.0.jar

Setup - GAE 1.6.5, JDK 1.7

Error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.naming.InitialContext is a restricted class.     Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
```

I thought this was because I was using different configuration so i changed to use the exact set up. Downgraded to GAE 1.6.3.1 and used the exact jars in the tutorial but it was no different.

So i tried the second tutorial which stated fix listed which involves replacing the jsf-impl.jar with jsf-impl-gae.jar but this has not helped.

After i do this I get the error:

```
WARNING: failed com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@1678d71{/,C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Google AppEngine JSF 2.0 Template\war}: java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 36 in method com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration.getServletContextName()Ljava/lang/String; at offset 10
May 07, 2012 5:07:17 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler@1547ec9: java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 36 in method com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration.getServletContextName()Ljava/lang/String; at offset 10
May 07, 2012 5:07:17 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Error starting handlers
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 36 in method com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration.getServletContextName()Ljava/lang/String; at offset 10
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:163)
```

I have also tried the guide [listed here](https://sites.google.com/a/wildstartech.com/adventures-in-java/Java-Platform-Enterprise-Edition/JavaServer-Faces/javaserver-faces-20/configuring-javaserver-faces-20-to-run-on-the-google-appengine)

I have tried every conceivable combination of tutorials here on two different app engine SDKs and two JDKs with the 7 jar i now have: el-api-2.2.1-b04.jar, el-impl-2.2.1-b05.jar, el-ri-1.0.jar, javax.faces-2.1.7.jar, javax.faces-2.1.7-sources.jar, jsf-api-2.1.7.jar, jsf-impl-gae.jar.

Any help would be greatly appreciated I think i will look for a different way to upload my project tomorrow as I have had nothing but trouble with JSF and Eclipse thus why I always use Netbeans however the GAE plugin for Netbeans is no longer functioning.

Thank you

Comment: You have a habit of using techniques that aren't supported in AppEngine. First, with the NetBeans plugin; second, with the JSF. You may have better luck if you use things that are supported and not restricted, as you may have to go through the same trouble again once Google releases SDK 1.7.0 or a future release. With that said, good luck finding your answer. My best advice is to turn up your logging level so you can see everything that's going on in the SDK and frameworks so you can possibly move through the issues. You also may have better luck if you can narrow the scope of the question.

Comment: The restricted class is most likely your biggest problem. You'll need to find someone who has renamed the library so the package name doesn't match GAE's list of non-whitelisted classes.

Comment: Could you clarify "things that are supported". Switch to a different framework?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to use restricted classes. `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.naming.InitialContext is a restricted class.`. And you mentioned you always have had trouble with JSF. I'm not sure if you can use Spring, but it's well supported in AppEngine. If; however, your business requirements necessitate the use of JSF on GAE, then my strong suggestion is to try and narrow down your question a bit. Also, you may want to indicate whether or not this runs on your local dev or is it only not working on production.

Comment: Basically, can you find out what JAR the InitialContext is in? Can you locate a repackaged alternative to that? Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/google-app-engine-jsf-2-example/comment-page-1/):

> 3.3 Create a new WebConfiguration.java.
>
> JSF 2 is using “javax.naming.InitialContext” that’s not support in GAE.
>
> To solve this, you need to get a copy of the JSF’s source code, clone the WebConfiguration.java, comment methods that are using “javax.naming.InitialContext” class, put it in “src/com/sun/faces/comfig/WebConfiguration.java“. Now, your newly created WebConfiguration.java class will overload the original WebConfiguration.java.

According to the tutorial, the class that is throwing your ClassDefNotFoundError is a retricted class. You'll need to visit [GAE-JSF javax.naming.InitialContext is a Restricted Class Source Code](http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/gae-jsf-javax-naming-initialcontext-is-a-restricted-class/) and retrieve a copy of the JSF source code and make a copy of the WebConfiguration Class and overload the original.

GAE's Whitelisting can be overrided by renaming packages or, in this case, avoiding them altogether. To clarify, what this step is asking you to do is replace WebConfiguration.java with one you modify where all methods using InitialContext are commented out. This hides that class from Google's whitelist so it doesn't force ClassNotFoundDefErrors.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have located two files where someone has already done this work however when i use these files the second error message in my post appears. I have been thinking of switching to Spring it always seems there are work arounds needed with JSF.

Comment: Those are after all, just warnings. Does the app not work even with those in place? Are you sure you've turned up your logging level to ALL so that you're sure to see all messages that may relate to the app not working? Maybe you can contact the guy/gal who wrote the article as it was only written within the last few weeks.

Comment: I'm  having the same issue for my web app, does this solution works even if deployed in the Appengine cloud, i.e the Appspot.com?

Comment: @xybrek - Yes, the problem was that the project ran on the dev server, but not the cloud. Follow the instructions above, and you'll eliminate the whitelisting errors. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. And here are the instructions that worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34630623/1317559