# Google App Engine + JSF 2 give the error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsf

I am using this linkfor google app engine with jsf so i am getting this error when i run the on eclipse so give the desire solution 
link is  http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/google-app-engine-jsf-2-example/

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass
     (IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:207)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer
    (JettyContainerService.java:197)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup
    (AbstractContainerService.java:241)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start
    (DevAppServerImpl.java:148)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply
    (DevAppServerMain.java:310)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>
     (DevAppServerMain.java:249)
     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main
     (DevAppServerMain.java:225)

  Sep 06, 2012 10:58:55 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
     SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
      javax.servlet.UnavailableException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:79)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer
    (JettyContainerService.java:197)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup
     (AbstractContainerService.java:241)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start
    (DevAppServerImpl.java:148)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply
    (DevAppServerMain.java:310)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.
    <init>(DevAppServerMain.java:249)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main
    (DevAppServerMain.java:225)

     Sep 06, 2012 10:58:55 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
   WARNING: failed Faces Servlet: java.lang.NullPointerException
    Sep 06, 2012 10:58:55 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
   WARNING: Failed startup of context
   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@1dc94ea
    {/,C:\Documents and Settings\Shilendra Sharma\workspace\Shilu\war}
     java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:256)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer
    (JettyContainerService.java:197)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup
    (AbstractContainerService.java:241)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start
    (DevAppServerImpl.java:148)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply
    (DevAppServerMain.java:310)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs
    (Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.
    <init>(DevAppServerMain.java:249)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main
    (DevAppServerMain.java:225)


   so any one help me for it work properly
```

App shilendra

Comment: This problem suggests that you didn't properly complete the step "2. JSF 2 Dependencies" as shown in the tutorial.

Comment: ok i can understand this is not enough for the google app engine with jsf in this tutorial

Answer (score 1):

JSF 2 is using “javax.naming.InitialContext” that’s not supported in GAE.

To solve this:

- You need to get a copy of the JSF’s source code. Copy the WebConfiguration.java
- Comment methods that are using "javax.naming.InitialContext" class
- But wait, I have modified the latest (jsf 2.2.12) and here it is: [WebConfiguration.java](http://pastebin.com/AcQDnc2G)
- Put it in the package com.sun.faces.config.

Now, your newly created WebConfiguration.java class will overload the original WebConfiguration.java.

Comment: hmm I dont quite understand where to put this file. Do I have to add the JSF jar to my project. then where? Or do I put it in my project source code and make a package "com.sun.face.config" in my own project? please help and explain

Comment: No, just make a new package: javax.naming.InitialContext . Then a new class: WebConfiguration . Then copy and paste the class contents from the file above into the new class.