# Using JSF 2.2.5 with Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsf, jsf-2, gae-eclipse-plugin

I have used Google App Engine for Python development, and I have some experience of Enterprise Java development using JSF2 on Tomcat.

However, I have been following [this guide](http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/google-app-engine-jsf-2-example/) to set up GAE with JSF2, but cannot get it to work.  The application builds with no errors, but throws a warning at runtime:

`WARNING: failed JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler@70e71bb9: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EnableTransitionTimeNoOpFlash`

Attempting to visit the **(local)** web application address in a browser shows a 404 error.

A Google search and search of StackOverflow returned zero results for this error.  Any help would be very much appreciated, as I'm using these technologies for my thesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to solve this.

It seems that when using Google App Engine API 1.9 and JSF 2.2.5, you no longer have to replace the WebConfiguration.java file.  Simply leaving the default file alone allows the code to run perfectly.

Comment: I have 2.2.6 and the same error. This solution doesn't work either. 
WARNING: Error starting handlers
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EnableTransitionTimeNoOpFlash
 at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext$ServletContextAdapter.<init>(InitFacesContext.java:316)

Comment: When EnableTransitionTimeNoOpFlash occurres I'm removing the WebConfiguration.java file and then the error is :============================java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.naming.InitialContext==============================
First search in internet is advising again to put WebConfiguration.java. And if I put the old 2.2.4 version of jsf (with overwritten WebConfiguration)then everything it's working

Comment: Here are the instructions that worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34630623/1317559