# javax.naming.initialcontext is a restricted class google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, active-directory, ldap, jndi

I try to connect to an ldap server using "javax.naming" my application is deployed on app engine

```
    public static DirContext connect(String ldapHote , String port, String distinguishedName ,String password ,String authentication) throws NamingException {
    DirContext context;
    Hashtable env;
    env = new Hashtable(11);
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://"+ldapHote+":"+port+"");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, distinguishedName);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,password );
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        context = new InitialDirContext(env);
        System.out.println("OK");
        return context;

}
```

but I have this error,  javax.naming.InitialContext is a restricted class. I wonder if there is a solution or there is another way to connect

Comment: http://www.infoworld.com/d/applications/google-apps-gains-ldap-support-891

Comment: Here are the instructions that worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34630623/1317559

Answer (score 1):

AppEngine runs a limited java [sandbox](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Java_The_sandbox), which does not provide all classes in the JRE standard library. Only classes on the [whitelist](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist) are available.  Unfortunately package `javax.naming.*` is not available.

Comment: so what's the solution ?

Comment: Try using a 3rd party lib for LDAP.